# Bicycles blog layout has overlapping fields

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, blog, blog-overflow

On the Bicycles Blog I've noticed that the field for entering your post extends under the "publish" and "categories" fields. Have emptied my cache and reloaded, and the problem persists.

[image: screenshot]

(You can see where the placeholder text extends under the fields on the right, blocking visibility of much text.)

Is anyone else seeing this? I've confirmed the problem on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari on my Mac.

Comment: @nhinkle, are you sure this is limited to the Bicycles' blog? (I would have guessed this was migrated to MSO because *all* blogs use the same software?)

Comment: @Arjan they all do run the same software, but each has a distinct design. I'm an admin for the Super User Blog and the problem doesn't appear there. I checked on the Bicycles Blog and it was a problem there. As of about a month ago, the SU Blog runs on the same server/WP instance as all the other site blogs.

Comment: I checked on SFF and the problem exists there as well.

Comment: The problem still exists on Bicycles and SFF.

Comment: CLearly this is not a priority. If SE wants its community blogs to do well, they need to be aware that serious usability problems like this will hamper participation. Anyone there? Hello?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to have been caused by the Wordpress 3.3.0 update. I have updated the network to 3.3.1 and we are no longer seeing this issue.